# How to decode this code ? php $_F=__FILE__;$_X= Byterun Decoder

Tags: php, decode, bytecode, encryption

I would like to decode this PHP page. I tried with [this site](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/byterun.php)  but when I decode code, the code is still encrypted :/

Can we help me please ?

**Page encrypted:**

```
<?php
$_F=__FILE__;
$_X='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';
$_D=strrev('edoced_46esab');
eval($_D('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCdTZ1BPOVlaV0ZLbXF5ZnhjakxKUnp1TTV2TnRzMWIue0I0bkNdaS8yRGwwRWhlQQpbZDg9UXA+VlhvIEh9NkdJdzdrYTNUclU8JywnPVI5b2RtcGxBRVB5azhndls1M3hyTWV6cVpIaTdZaFc8RHNHez5DY1h9MU4vYWZqNl1KdHVTIAouQlVud1ZLTFFPMjBJVEY0YicpOyRfUj1zdHJfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw='));
?>
```

Comment: It seems like this script is connecting to a license server to make sure that you have a valid license to run it. Are you really trying to decode it for legitimate purposes?

Comment: No way to edit the page ? Because it's just form to be signup and I want to translate form in french :(

Comment: That's awesome `strrev('edoced_46esab')`

Comment: Yes. I have lisence but login.php is encrypted. And I want to change the html. But in login.php there are just this fu... code :/

Comment: Can you ask the author/seller to make these changes for you?

Comment: Yes I have sent a mail 1 week ago... no answer

Script is instant-leads.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pastebin.com/JHWeqsgj) is your plain source code of the asked file.

As I said in a post earlier today. If you have access to the .php file, you have access to the source no matter what.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy. Your encrypted file looks like this:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='encrypted text';eval(base64_decode('rubbish'));?>
```

Paste just the 'encrypted text' section into the top box of [this page](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/byterun.php) and hit <kbd>Decode This Rubbish</kbd>.

Comment: The page you mention is given as reference in the question. The OP claims that the it doesn't work for him. Neither for me. At least I don't get the code as decoded and provided by @TraianTatic. Did you verify that your proposed method actually works?